# Codeigniter validation always return false

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm a beginner in coding. I'm having a problem with the CI Validation, it's always return false.[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obeEW.png)

and this my controller:
`

```
//session_start();

Class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load database
        $this->load->model('login_pegawai');
    }

    // Show login page
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('utama');
    }

    // Check for employee login process
    public function process() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
                $this->load->view('pegawai/dashboard_pegawai');
            } else {
                $this->load->view('utama');
            }
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'username' => ($this->input->post('username')),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
            );
            $result = $this->login_pegawai->login($data);
            if ($result == TRUE) {

                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $result = $this->login_pegawai->read_user_information($username);
                if ($result != false) {
                    $session_data = array(
                        'username' => $result[0]->username,
                        'email' => $result[0]->email,
                    );
                    // Add user data in session
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
                    $this->load->view('pegawai/dashboard_pegawai');
                }
            } else {
                $data = array(
                    'error_message' => '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />'
                );
                $this->load->view('utama', $data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>`

and my model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Login_pegawai extends CI_Model {

    // Read data using username and password
    public function login($data) {

        $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . md5($data['password']) . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pegawai');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Read data from database to show data in employee page
    public function read_user_information($username) {

        $condition = "username =" . "'" . $username . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pegawai');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

?>

and finally my view:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Bank Sampah</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('assets/home/layout/styles/layout.css'); ?>" type="text/css" /></head>
<body id="top">

<div class="wrapper col1">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="<?php echo base_url('home')?>">Bank Sampah</a></h1>
            <p><strong>Reuse, Reduce, Recycle</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div id="newsletter">
            <p>Login Pegawai</p>
            <form action='<?php echo base_url('home/process'); ?>' method='post' name='process'>
                          <?php echo "<div class='error_msg'>";
                            if (isset($error_message)) {
                                echo $error_message;
                            }
                            echo validation_errors();
                            echo "</div>";
                          ?>
                    <input type="username" placeholder="Username&hellip;" id="username" name="username"  onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Name&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password&hellip;" id="password" name="password" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Password&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />
                    <input type="submit" id="news_go" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper col2">
    <div id="topbar">
        <div id="topnav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url('home')?>">Home</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="<?php echo base_url('login')?>">Login Nasabah & Pengepul</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col3">
    <div id="breadcrumb">
        <ul>
            <li class="first">You Are Here</li>
            <li>&#187;</li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col5">
    <div id="container">
        <center><img class="gambar"/></center>
        <br><br>
        <h1>BANK SAMPAH</h1>
        <p>Bank Sampah adalah suatu tempat yang digunakan untuk mengumpulkan sampah yang sudah dipilah-pilah.</p>
        <p>Hasil dari pengumpulan sampah yang sudah dipilah akan disetorkan ke tempat pembuatan kerajinan sampah atau ke tempat pengepul sampah.</p>
        <p>Bank Sampah dikelola menggunakan sistem seperti perbankan yang dilakukan oleh petugas sukarelawan.</p>
        <p>Penyetor adalah warga yang tinggal di sekitar lokasi bank serta mendapat buku tabungan seperti menabung di bank.</p>
     <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col6">
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="footbox">
            <h2>More Info</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footbox">
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footbox">
            <h2>Lacus interdum</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footbox">
            <h2>Lacus interdum</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Praesent et eros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper col7">
    <div id="copyright">

        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried many ways but the results are showing me the same. Please let me know where I'm mistaken. Sorry for speaking/writing bad English, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with your validation or with query? please check my answer

Comment: Did you load the form validation helper?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm creating this with one of my friend, he said that our validation is the problem, I've tried to fix the validation but the result are same as before, it return false.

Yes, I did load the form_validation helper in my autoload.php

Comment: It still came out with the same error. When I'm trying to login with the right username and password, it still shown "Invalid username and/or password" :(

Comment: yes I did, I already tried that. still it doesn't work. I've also tried adding $this->db->last_query(); under $this->db->get(); and still it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you run  your last query on mysql? what is the result?

Comment: `username` is not a valid `input` `type`.

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with your login function, when you have multiple conditions in where clause, the second and third parameters should be define as well.

```
public function login($data) {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pegawai');
        $this->db->where("username",$data['username']);
        $this->db->where("password",$data['password']);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I've tried it but it still return false like in the picture.

Comment: Is query returns false?